# How to get size of QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, size, qgraphicsview

I have problem trying to get correct size of QGraphicsView. The size() method always returns 640x480. Why is it constant? Even when I resize the app it still is the same. I want to have a QGraphicsView that resizes automatically, fill the entire app and get current size of it.

My code now (constructor of my QMainWindow class):

```
auto graph = ui->graph;
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
graph->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);
graph->setScene(scene);
graph->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 230, 179)));
```

And then I try this (some method of another class which gets called on button click):

```
QSize size = graphicsView->size();
```

The width of size is always 640 and heigth always 480 no matter if I resize the main window or run the app in tiny window (QGraphicsView resizes automatically when resizing the window).
I also tried to get the heigth and width of QGraphicsScene with:

```
scene->heigth();
scene->width();
```

but both return 0.

How can I get the correct dimensions of the QGraphicsView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the question and added some code.

Comment: I do not want some code, I have asked you for a MRE

Comment: resize your scene as you resize your main window using signals from main window.

Comment: scene and view have different sizes. Imagine the view being a window and the scene being the landscape beyond the window. The graphics view size can be significantly smaller (or bigger) than the scene.
Is it possible that you're calling size() of a different QGraphicsView instance? (I just noticed that in the first code snipped, you named your variable 'graph', in the second it's 'graphicsView')